# When do resource-generating skills work on destructible objects?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've noticed that when attacking an object (e.g. a barrel) with a fury-generating skill as a Barbarian, I generate fury as if I would have attacked a monster. Attacking a barrel with a spirit-generating skill, however, does not generate spirit.

My question is, when do resource-generation skills actually generate resources when attacking an object?

- Does it only depend on the class?
- Does it depend on the specific skills used?
- Does it matter if the object is a red-highlighted one (e.g. a barrel) or a non-highlighted one (e.g. a tombstone act 1 graveyard)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on the class:

- Barbarians generate fury whenever they successfully hit an enemy or destroyable object with a fury generator.
- Monks generate spirit whenever they successfully hit an enemy (but not destroyable object) with a spirit generator.
- Demon Hunters regenerate hatred merely by using a hatred generating skill, whether it hits or not.

The other two classes don't have "generator" skills and rely on passive generation.

Comment: Wait, so just shooting into a wall as a DH generates hatred?

Comment: @Oak Yep. Hatred comes back rather fast overall, and the generators don't generate a huge amount.

Comment: Does Fury only generate when hitting certain destructable objects (barrels/urns but not tables/chairs)?

Comment: @NickT It generates hitting anything destructible that hasn't already been destroyed. Even candles.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Blizzard](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/3123245774) (under "Combat"):

Due to degenerative nature of the Barbarian's Fury, it should be generated by attacking environment objects, but since Monk's Spirit is not degenerative, it should not be generated by attacking environment objects.